# How to change the Currency Rate in a bill or invoice with Acumatica API?

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to create a bill and invoice through the Acumatica API.

I have looked for a solution but I can't find where i can change the currency rate with the API.

Answer (score 0):

The rates cannot be changed per Bill Item.  Rates are managed in Currency Management preferences.  But below is an example which creates a bill with a currency  other than the default currency for the Vendor.  In this case, I used CAD

Put:  http://yourErpInstance/entity/Default/18.200.001/Bill

```
{
"Vendor" : {value : "AAVENDOR" } ,
"VendorRef" : {value : "987654" }, 
"CurrencyID" : {value : "CAD" }
}
```

If you want to manage the currency rate preferences, you must extend your endpoint and include the header & details in your extended endpoint.  Below is an example.
[image]